# How to pass in a Variable for a Class method Call in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a basic app to help my Monday Night 5 a side football (soccer) team update our stats each week. Including goals, assists and how many times we hoof the ball over the fence.

I've created a data class to represent each player, this needs updating according to user input.

```
 data class player(
    val name: String = "",
    var goals: Int = 0,
    var assists: Int = 0
    )

val TestPlayerName:String = "Bob"
val GoalsOrAssists:String = "goals"
    
fun main() {

    var Team: List <player> =   listOf(
        
            player(name="Dave", goals=0, assists=0), 
            player(name="Bob",  goals=0, assists=0), 
            player(name="Barry", goals=0, assists=0), 
            player(name="Bill", goals=0, assists=0)
    )

    
    Team.forEach { player ->
        if(player.name == TestPlayerName){
            player.goals =+ 1
        }
    }
    println(Team)
}
```

The code above correctly prints out that Bob has notched up a goal...

```
[player(name=Dave, goals=0, assists=0), 
player(name=Bob, goals=1, assists=0), 
player(name=Barry, goals=0, assists=0), 
player(name=Bill, goals=0, assists=0)]
```

But I'm struggling to find out how to pass a variable into the mix as either goals or assists will need to be updated dynamically according to user input. For example...

```
Team.forEach { player ->
        if(player.name == TestPlayerName){
            player.**insertVariableHere** += 1
        }
    }
```

Any advice much appreciated :)

Comment: `if (player.name == TestPlayerName) { if (someOtherThing) { player.goals += 1} else { player.assists += 1 } }`

Comment: There are a number of stats more than just Goals and Assists and this list will increase over time. For example Goals, Assists, Whacking ball over the fence etc. The stat will change each time therefore an if statement would be a pain to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just two variables, I'd prefer using just a `Boolean`, then just check it and set different properties depending on its value.

```
var isAssist = true

...
// please follow naming conventions!
team.forEach { player ->
    if(player.name == testPlayerName){
        if (isAssist) {
            player.assists += 1
        } else {
            player.goals += 1
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of properties you want to do this with, and writing `if` cases for everything would end up being very long, you can make `goalsOrAssists` be of type `KMutableProperty1<Player, Int>`.

```
data class Player(
   val name: String = "",
   var goals: Int = 0,
   var assists: Int = 0
)

val testPlayerName:String = "Bob"
val goalsOrAssists: KMutableProperty1<Player, Int> = 
    Player::goals
    // or
    Player::assists
```

You can then set it using the `get` and `set` methods:

```
team.forEach { player ->
    if(player.name == testPlayerName){
        goalsOrAssists.set(player, goalsOrAssists.get(player) + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the OP's apparent newness to Kotlin and programming, I would reverse the answers in your question, or entirely delete the entire section about `KMutableProperty`...

Answer (score 1):

> There are a number of stats more than just Goals and Assists and this list will increase over time. For example Goals, Assists, Whacking ball over the fence etc

It would be fragile, but for your relatively simple app, you could store a map of name of stat to amount of the stat:

```
data class Player(
   val name: String = "",
   var stats = mutableListOf<String, Int>()
)

fun main() {

    var Team: List <player> =   listOf(
        player(name="Dave"), 
        player(name="Bob"), 
        player(name="Barry"), 
        player(name="Bill")
    )


    Team.forEach { player ->
    if(player.name == TestPlayerName){
        player.stats["goals"] =+ 1
        player.stats["whackingballoverfence"] += 30
    }
}
println(Team)
}
```